# Getting classes to work in java, building a Android App to parse XML

Tags: java, android, class

Okay so my first app, I got an XML parser working. In the same class it works fine, but if i seperate it to a new class/java file, It doesnt work, compiles fine but wont load in AVD. Could someone please look at my classes, ill include im imports etc as well because i think it has something to do with the namespace...Any help much appreciated

```
package com.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
// import com.helloworld.XMLParse;

//import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloworldActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    XMLParse xml_parse = new XMLParse();
    xml_parse.doXML();

    }

}
```

And the main class to do the job in my package is,

package com.helloworld;
import java.io.IOException;

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParse extends Activity {

public void doXML() {

    TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_xml);
    String stringXmlContent;
    try {
        stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
        myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
        {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            Resources res = activity.getResources();
            XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
            xpp.next();
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {
                    stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                {
                    stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                {
                    stringBuffer.append("\nTEXT: "+xpp.getText());
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
            stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
            return stringBuffer.toString();
        }
}
```

Comment: I resolved this, I have the code at http://www.anddev.org/post113084.html#p113084

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about android but it looks weird to me that your XMLParse is inheriting from Activity.

Maybe it shouldn't and you should pass in your HelloworldActiviy:

```
public void doXML(Activity activity) {
    TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.my_xml);
    String stringXmlContent;
    try {
        stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(activity);
        myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In android, Activities are displayable components for your app. You can't directly instantiate an Activity because it relies on a bunch of OS code to be created and maintained properly. There is a lot wrong here, but at a high level you really don't want the functionality of parsing XML to extend Activity. It doesn't seem to make sense to have a method called getEventsFromAnXML which takes an Activity as a parameter.